# Thymeleaf show html file name instead of its content

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Thymeleaf doesn't show html but only their name!

this is my configuration on `application.properties`

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/
```

this is my controller

```
@GetMapping({"", "/"})
public ModelAndView home(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("web/index");
    return mav;
}
```

this is the file system

```
|--  src
  |-- main
     |-- java
     |-- resource
         |-- application.properties
     |-- web
         |-- index.html
```

When I launch `mvn clean spring-boot:run` and I go to `http://localhost` I get a web page with this content ( the name on html file )

```
web/index
```

Comment: Is your controller a `@RestController` instead of a regular `@Controller`?

Answer (score 0):

change file system to this and try again:

```
|--  src
  |-- main
     |-- java
     |-- resource
         |--templates
            |-- web
               |-- index.html
         |-- application.properties
```